# How do you test a function which is called with a constant using jasmine + TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I'm working on a Angular2 / TypeScript Project and using jasmine for unit-testing.

How to test a function which is called with a constant using jasmine.
Eg.
Logo.ts

```
export const RADIUS: number = 10;

export class Logo {
  ...
  protected drawCircle( x: number, y: number, r: number ){...}

  protected drawLogo(){
    this.drawCircle( RADIUS, RADIUS, RADIUS );
  }
  ...
}
```

Logo.spec.ts

```
describe('drawLogo', function () {
  beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn( logo, 'drawCircle');
  }
  it('should call drawCircle method with parameters'){
    expect( logo.drawCircle ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( 10, 10, 10 ); //This fails
  }
}
```

Is there any other way to test other than passing the constant as parameter to toHaveBeenCalledWith method ?

Comment: You can use `logo.drawCircle.calls.mostRecent().args` for a bit more flexibility.

Comment: you never call drawLogo() in your test. How should that then work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use a spy first

```
spyOn('logo','drawCircle');
logo.drawLogo();
 expect( logo.drawCircle ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( 10, 10, 10 );
```

Comment: @tymspy so, what is the solution? because you did the same in the code you just posted

Comment: @iberbeu i have missed calling the method as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

import the RADIUS to your spec file and then

```
expect( logo.drawCircle ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( RADIUS, RADIUS, RADIUS );
```